# Conditional formatting in webi Rich Client 4.1 of multiple values

Tags: conditional-formatting, webi

I'm in BO 4.1 using a crosstab table.  It is summary data based off specific detail information.  Example:
Area-Days Late-Order #-Reason
1 - 5 - 12345-Lost
1 - 2 - 843254 - Lost
2 - 4 - 7532384 - Lost
1 - 7 - 12353 - Not home

So the output would be

```
     Area 1    Area 2
```

Lost       2          1
Not home   1          0

Now for the conditional formatting part, I want it to highlight the Area 1 Lost cell as red because two of the orders are greater than 3 days late.

For whatever reason it seems to not be doing it because it's getting hung up line item 2 because that one is less than 3 days late.

Thank you!

Comment: I cheated and created a new object and then summed and did an if statement.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

I cheated and created a new object and then summed and did an if statement.  Thanks for looking at this.